# New subdomain - how to redirect from old one to new using rewrites?

Tags: windows, redirection, iis

Inside the organization the internal system websites are given as sub-domains.

So now many people have the old link to the home page of one of the websites saved in their favorites - `old_domain.example.com`. So I need to redirect to the new domain `new_domain.example.com`.

I clicked on the website, then clicked `URL Rewrite`, and got to this window:

[image]

However I am not sure if I'm in the right place. If I am - how do I write the map? The dropdown is empty there, so nothing to choose from.

Do I need to first create a map somewhere else, then choose it here? Or I can directly write the map inside? Or, it's completely something else?

**Edit:** I could not follow these instructions, because `HTTP Redirect` button does not exist in my IIS, so I will need to do it with rewrite rules if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082219/redirect-subdomain-url-to-another-subdomain-in-iis